# Combining options

Tags: plotting, options

Consider the function

```
fTest[b_] := Plot[a Sin[x] + b ,{x, -4, 4}],
```

where `a` is some real constant.

I can set some standard value for `a` by `Options[fTest] = {a -> 4}` and define `fTest` as:

```
fTest[b_, OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[OptionValue[a] Sin[x] + b, {x, -4, 4}]
```

Now `fTest` should also accept the usual options of `Plot`.

I tried

```
Options[fTest] = {a -> 4, Options[Plot]} // Flatten;
fTest[b_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Plot[OptionValue[a] Sin[x] + b, {x, -4, 4}, opts]
```

which failed.

A workaround could be achieved via:

```
fTest[b_, a_: 4, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Plot[a*Sin[x] + b, {x, -4, 4}, opts]
```

This works, but I would favor a solution where the option is of the form `a -> value`

So how can I combine the options?

Comment: You need to remove the option `a->4` from the options that are fed to Plot. The easiest way is to use `Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Plot]` instead of `opts` in your Plot.

Comment: @CarlWoll, thank you for your answer, it works.
I will accept it, if you are willing to post it as an answer.